# I cannot find the file /var/lib/mlocate.db

Tags: locate

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS installed on my Raspberry Pi and I try to find/open the file /var/lib/mlocate.db but I cannot find it.

I installed locate package.

It's because I'm doing an online course from Linux Professional Institute (LPI) and I read this passage:

> One problem with locate is that it only shows entries present in the
> database generated by updatedb (located in /var/lib/mlocate.db). If
> the database is outdated, the output could show files that have been
> deleted since the last time it was updated. One way to avoid this is
> to add the -e parameter, which will make it check to see if the file
> still exists before showing it on the output.

So I would like to see the database.

Comment: That database is updated with a cron job / systemd timer. You can either wait for a day for that job to run, or start it manually (`sudo updatedb`). See `man locatedb` for documentation about the format. It's binary, so opening it with a text editor won't be very useful.

Comment: Did you install mlocate or plocate? If the latter, please run: `sudo updatedb` and then check /var/lib/plocate/plocate.db.

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu now uses `plocate` as the default - see [Jammy Jellyfish Release Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668)

Comment: Thank you @HuHa @chili555 and @steeldriver.  Yes with Ubuntu version 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish), I installed plocate (not mlocate) so the binary file ``/var/lib/mlocate.db`` referred in the LPI passage in my question, its equivalent for plocate is located there ``/var/lib/plocate/plocate.db``.